# How do I create a library in FCPX 10.5 with Final Cut Projects and Final Cut Events folders?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

There're some online tutorials that have materials organised into 2 folders: Final Cut Projects and Final Cut Events, if they're in 'Movies'.

[image: tutorial materials]

Their videos show that older version of FCP seems to recognise these folders by default, and can browse projects and events in these folders directly.

[image: older version of FCP can browse file system directly]

I'm using FCPX 10.5, and I can't find out how to import those projects and events into a new library.

Answer (score 0):

If you click the dropdown in your library, you will see a folder named "Smart Collections" under that, you'll see Projects. Any and all Events will be under your Library hierarchy, these folders will be created automatically.
[image: Screenshot of FCPX Library Hierarchy]

Comment: Thank you, Ishaan. But sorry, I didn't describe it clearly. I've added some screenshots now.